# Why can't find which program is using port 1080?

Tags: port-forwarding, wireshark

To open wireshark and select interfaces lo,here is graph captured all packages between port 1080 and others in 127.0.0.1.

[image]

1.Why the number of other ports in 127.0.0.1 is always increasing?
The port number inceased from 48239 until 48250.

2.Why can't find which program is using  port  1080?

```
sudo  netstat -alnp  |grep 1080
```

It get nothing.
The plugin--Proxy SwitchyOmega in chrome play the trick.
[image]

I change proxy into direct ,no tcp packages send into port 1080 now.

[image]

**fuser socks/tcp** can't give the pid number,it output nothing.

I still want to know how to get the pid when plugin--Proxy SwitchyOmega in chrome was set to use socks5 proxy and continuously to send tcp packages into port 1080.

Comment: maybe this can help `cat /etc/services | grep 1080 #socks           1080/tcp ` then `fuser socks/tcp` should give the pid...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2. Nobody is listening on Port 1080, that's why your TCP packets are rejected (you send SYN to 1080, nobody is listening, so you get back RST, ACK and TCP connection is terminated)
3. Each connection attempt use another port, this is how ephemeral ports work.